# How can I put a series of loop calculations into a vector

Tags: r

I've generated the following code and want to put the five values calculated by the for loop into a single vector. I've spent several hours searching various sites and have not found anything that will allow me to do that.

```
> complete<-function(directory,ID){
+ files_list <- list.files( directory , full.names=TRUE) #creates a list of files
+ dat <- data.frame() #creates an empty data frame
+ for (i in 1:332) { #loops through the files, rbinding them together
+   dat <- rbind(dat, read.csv(files_list[i]))
+ }
+ cleandat<-na.omit(dat)
+ for(i in ID){
+ n<-nrow(cleandat[cleandat$ID %in% i,])
+ print(n)
+ }
+  
+ #return(ndat)
+ }
> complete("specdata", ID<-c(2,4,8,10,12))
[1] 1041
[1] 474
[1] 192
[1] 148
[1] 96
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `print`, just gather together the final result and `return` that

```
complete<-function(directory,ID){
result<- rep(NA,length(ID))
files_list <- list.files( directory , full.names=TRUE) #creates a list of files
dat <- data.frame() #creates an empty data frame
for (i in 1:332) { #loops through the files, rbinding them together
dat <- rbind(dat, read.csv(files_list[i]))
}
cleandat<-na.omit(dat)
for(i in ID){
n<-nrow(cleandat[cleandat$ID %in% i,])
result[i]<-n
}  
return(result)
}
```

Comment: It's best to preallocate memory instead of using `c` repeatedly

Answer (score 1):

This would be much faster and easier than the for-loop (although I am worried that you are thereby throwing away the dat object with all the data in it):

```
result <- table(dat$ID)[ID]
```

The suggestion to use `return` is not necessary. The result of the last evaluation is automatically returned from a function. If you wanted to print it as a side-effect, then the `print` function (unlike the `cat` function) also returns its argument, so fell free to wrap `print(. <- .)` around the assignment.